# jQuery validation plugin not validating my forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble using the jQuery validation (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin with one of my forms. I made a jsFiddle so that nobody has to see my ugly coded 9000 lined form:

http://jsfiddle.net/ndaMD/

source:

```
<form id="yeah">
First name: <input type="text" class="required" id="firstname" minlength=”4”><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
</form>

<a href="#" id="test123">HELLO</a>


$('#test123').click(function(){

    $( "#yeah" ).validate({
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the validator on dom ready and then on the click event call the `valid()` method to see whether the form is valid

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#yeah").validate({});


    $('#test123').click(function () {
        if ($("#yeah").valid()) {
            console.log('do')
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4buV8/)